# Filenames in paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

Hey so I have a class called Asset and each Asset has an :attachment. I want to take the :basename.:extension of the uploaded file and store it in the :asset_file_name. How do I go about doing so? here is my class:

```
    class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :asset_file_name, :lesson_id, :attachment

    #allows us to use :lesson_id in :url
    Paperclip.interpolates :lesson_id do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.lesson_id
    end

    has_attached_file :attachment,
    :url => "/attachments/:lesson_id/:basename.:extension",
    :path => ":rails_root/public/attachments/:lesson_id/:basename.:extension"

    validates_presence_of :asset_file_name
    validates_attachment_presence :attachment

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you'd want to have an asset_file_name attribute

but you should be able to get it through `attachment_file_name`